# Is there a way to get xml element?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, attributes

I have the following XML I am parsing through to get some values and make store them in a file, I am able to get attributes however when I try to pull the value I need I get `none` when using `x.get()` like in the example, could you help me understand what's happening? and how can I get the values I need?

This is an example of the xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<sbml xmlns:fbc="http://www.sbml.org/sbml/level3/version1/fbc/version2" level=3 sboTerm="SBO:0000624" version="1" xmlns=""http://www.sbml.org/sbml/level3/version1/core" fbc:required="false">
   <model id="iJR904" fbc:strict="true">
      <listOfUnitDefinitions> fobo </listOfUnitDefinitions>
      <fbc:listOfObjectives fbc:activeObjective="obj> Objectives </fbc:listOfObjectives>
      <listOfParameters>
         <parameter constant="true" id="cobra_default_lb" sboTerm="SBO:0000626" units="mmol_per_gDW_per_hr" value="-999999" />
         <parameter constant="true" id="cobra_default_ub" sboTerm="SBO:0000626" units="mmol_per_gDW_per_hr" value="999999" />
         <parameter constant="true" id="cobra_0_bound" sboTerm="SBO:0000626" units="mmol_per_gDW_per_hr" value="0" />
         <parameter constant="true" id="R_ATPM_upper_bound" sboTerm="SBO:0000625" units="mmol_per_gDW_per_hr" value="7.6" />
         <parameter constant="true" id="R_ATPM_lower_bound" sboTerm="SBO:0000625" units="mmol_per_gDW_per_hr" value="7.6" />
         <parameter constant="true" id="R_EX_glc_DASH_D_e_lower_bound" sboTerm="SBO:0000625" units="mmol_per_gDW_per_hr" value="-10" />
         <parameter constant="true" id="R_EX_o2_e_lower_bound" sboTerm="SBO:0000625" units="mmol_per_gDW_per_hr" value="-20" />
       </listOfParameters>
       <listOfCompartments> Compartments</listOfCompartments>
       <listOfSpecies> Species</listOfSpecies>
       <fbc:listOfGeneProducts> Products </fbc:listOfGeneProducts>
       <listOfReactions>
         <reaction fast="false" id="R_12PPDt" name="S-Propane-1,2-diol facilitated transport" reversible="true" fbc:lowerFluxBound="cobra_default_lb" fbc:upperFluxBound="cobra_default_ub">
         </reaction>
         <reaction fast="false" id="R_2DGLCNRx" name="2-dehydro-D-gluconate reductase (NADH)" reversible="false" fbc:lowerFluxBound="cobra_0_bound" fbc:upperFluxBound="cobra_default_ub">
         </reaction>
       </listOfReactions>
   </model>
</sbml>
```

The code I wrote in Python is like this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
mytree =  ET.parse('iJR904.xml')
myroot = mytree.getroot()

mychild = myroot[0]

for a in range(len(mychild[6])):
       print(mychild[6][a].get('id'),':',mychild[6][a].get('fbc:lowerFluxBound'))
```

It prints:

```
R_12PPDt : none
R_2DGLCNRx : none
```

Since I want value not really the text I thought I could use some `if` like this:

```
for a in range(len(mychild[6])):
    if mychild[6][a].get('fbc:lowerFluxBound') == 'cobra_default_lb':
        print(mychild[6][a].get('id'),':',-999999)

    elif mychild[6][a].get('fbc:lowerFluxBound') == 'cobra_0_bound':
        print(mychild[6][a].get('id'),':',0)
```

Comment: what do you get if you print `id` and `name`?

Comment: You are getting tripped up on namespaces. If you can use lxml, this can be done relatively easily.

Comment: Thanks, I will dive into lxml, I have no idea about it but as long as it helps

Comment: If you can use lxml, I can post an answer.

Comment: so, I tried with `x.get('fbc:lowerFluxBound')` but still gives me `none` unless there's another way that I am not getting from lxml

Comment: @jsotola I tried and it pulls the id and the name, it works for all but `fbc:lowerFluxBound` tag and `fbc:upperFluxBound`, even if I pull `x.get('reversible)` the outcome is `true` or `false` accordingly

Comment: that tell me that it has no trouble pulling the second value ... so the problem is probably the tag name ... what happens if you use the tag name `fbc\:lowerFluxBound`?

Comment: @jsotola still pulls `None`

Comment: just found the answer, first I went through `x.attrib()` to check all the attributes in the tag, then noticed that specifically for the element I want the name is not stored as `fbc:lowerFluxBound` rather another name once I use that name everything seems to work out, lesson learned, check the attributes thanks all for your answers

Comment: @alexandervindel please teach us ... what was the stored name?

Comment: @jsotola basically the complete name was stored in the `fbc:` part of it once I ran the `x.attrib()` I could see the full name and it was like this `{http://www.sbml.org/sbml/level3/version1/fbc/version2}:lowerFluxBound` my guess is that `fbc:` stored the url as a reference of some sort, but I think it can be parsed with some regular expressions, still haven't completelly figured how to do it without cheking the `x.attrib()`

Answer (score 1):

You're a good researcher and can figure out what's wrong. This should be caused by the namespace in the XML syntax. The following library ignores the syntax of the namespace and treats it as a normal string.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils

xml = utils.getFileContent('iJR904.xml')
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
listOfReactions = doc.selects('listOfReactions>reaction')
# print (listOfReactions)

print ([(a.id,a['fbc:lowerFluxBound']) for a in listOfReactions])
```

Result:

```
[('R_12PPDt', 'cobra_default_lb'), ('R_2DGLCNRx', 'cobra_0_bound')]
```

Comment: That's very useful and makes things simpler, thanks a lot